# Python: Split a line of numbers separated by spaces

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python. I want to split a line with numbers

Eg
number_line= 9000 -0.3         89000

I tried using re.split as there maybe consecutive spaces

```
number_line_split=re.split('\s+',number_line)
```

But I get the error:
“Expected string or bytes-like object”

Thank you

Comment: where did you get your `number_line`?

Comment: Only tangential to your question, but: if you call .split() on a string without giving a separator, or giving the separator as None, it will split on any consecutive run of whitespace characters.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

perhaps convert `number_line` to a string with `str(number_line)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to first surround your line with quotes so Python interprets it as a string:

```
number_line = "9000 -0.3 89000"
```

You can then use the [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method to create a new list containing each number as a string, with extra whitespace handled:

```
>>> number_line_split = number_line.split()
>>> number_line_split
['9000', '-0.3', '89000']
```

And if you want to convert the remaining strings into actual numbers you can do arithmetic with, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to call `float()` on each string:

```
>>> numbers = [float(s) for s in number_line_split]
>>> numbers
[9000.0, -0.3, 89000.0]
>>> numbers[0] + numbers[1]
8999.7
```

The TypeError you got before was because `number_line` was an invalid type when it was passed into `re.split`. If `number_line` is a string, it would work just fine, although you would still need to convert the list of strings into floats afterwards:

```
>>> import re
>>> number_line = "9000 -0.3 89000"
>>> re.split('\s+', number_line)
['9000', '-0.3', '89000']
```